# How to install a local package from a local source?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this git repo: https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner

I downloaded it with `git clone https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner`.

Then I tried to install it from its parent dir with:

```
npm install --save smart-app-banner
```

This always installs the source from the github repo instead of from the local source.

**How do I get the source being install from the local copy instead of from github?**

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do, are you always installing package?

Comment: I want do download this repo https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner then modify the source and compile my modification. How can I do that?

Comment: Even if you make changes how are you going to maintain that, you have your own npm repository. As in future when you download this dependency you will require to download from your repo right?

Comment: @Sohan I want do make changes to make pull requests.

Comment: This is not my repo. I want to compile the local copy of the repo. How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't have any repository to maintain then it will be manual process say, that you commit full module in git, then you copy  your modified smart banner-app to node_modules of root project before compiling your main project . Something like this manula step may require

Comment: Sorry I am new with npm. Please make this not harder. I just want to know how do I compile the local copy of this repo. Nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87997/discussion-between-sohan-and-confile).

Answer (score 2):

npm install /path

it is as simple as that

Comment: it alway installs the source from github. And the problem is that I have no idea how to compile the source?

Comment: @confile you need to make sure that `npm` knows you want to install from a directory, so use `npm install ./smart-app-banner`.

Comment: This works but it does not build the code? How do I build it?

Comment: @confile `cd smart-app-banner; npm run build; cd ..; npm i ./smart-app-banner` (probably)

Answer (score 1):

If you run npm install without any arguments, it tries to install the current  folder.
Go to that folder and type npm Install
or
Just put that downloaded File in Node_modules folder of your project.

Comment: I tried this with the repo above but it alway installs the repo from github instead of my local modifications.

Comment: No u dont have to use repo name. if you are in the same directory just type npm install

Comment: But this does not compile the source. How do I compile the source?